# How to implement the SlopeOne recommender in Mahout 0.9?

Tags: mahout, mahout-recommender

I'm new to Mahout and am trying to work through 'Mahout in Action,' which uses the 0.5 release. One of the early examples calls for using the slope-one recommender. Is this recommender still included in Mahout 0.9?  I've looked through the documentation and I couldn't find it. Perhaps it has changed names?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no SlopeOneRecommender present in Mahout 0.9. It was removed in an earlier version of Mahout.

SlopeOne Recommender was removed from Mahout 0.8 onwards [MAHOUT-1250](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1250)

If you want to still use it, use an earlier version such as Mahout 0.7.